# How to select distinct records

Tags: sql, sql-server

Work on Sql server 2005.Want to select distinct records.On base on one column Like:NID want to get distinct records

Below picture describes in detail:

[image]

Comment: you want the output as you have it in the image ?

Comment: I don't understand why if you want distinct records where `NID = 10` that you are only returning the row with an ID of 5.  Could you explain why the others have been excluded?

Comment: whats wrong with select * from tablename where nid = 10 ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
;with ff as 
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NID ORDER BY ID DESC) Num, *
    FROM Table1
)
SELECT * FROM ff WHERE Num = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY FName,MName,Name ORDER BY ID) AS rno,
    FName,MName,Name,ID
FROM tableName
WHERE NID=10
)

SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE  rno=1
```

This will return the distinct record for `NID=10` based on `FName,MName,Name`.
i.e. Having unique `FName,MName,Name`

Comment: He asked for "On base on one column Like:NID"

Comment: @rudym But his result is based on the Distinct of `FName,MName,Name` in `NID=10`

Comment: distinction based on one column NID, that is what written there.

Comment: @rudym What will be the output of your query? NID=10 will return more thn one record. Since you are partitioning using NID , that will be always greater than 1 and wont return any value. He is expecting a unique result with NID=10. have a look at the image he is given.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DECLARE @NID INT 

SET @NID = 10; 

WITH nidgroup 
     AS (SELECT id, 
                name, 
                fname, 
                mname, 
                nid 
         FROM   people 
         WHERE  nid = @NID) 
SELECT * 
FROM   people 
WHERE  nid = @NID 
       AND name NOT IN (SELECT name 
                        FROM   nidgroup 
                        GROUP  BY name 
                        HAVING Count(*) > 1) 
       AND fname NOT IN (SELECT fname 
                         FROM   nidgroup 
                         GROUP  BY fname 
                         HAVING Count(*) > 1) 
       AND mname NOT IN (SELECT mname 
                         FROM   nidgroup 
                         GROUP  BY mname 
                         HAVING Count(*) > 1)
```

**Note** The PARTITION solutions return false results when there is no distinct value to return. Try removing row 5 from the table.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply based on your specifications "Why exclude from the output list" and your example output.

```
SELECT  ID
        Name ,
        Fname ,
        Mname ,
        NID
FROM    tableName
WHERE   NID = 10
        AND Name <> 'a'
        AND FName <> 'y'
        AND Mname <> 'gg'
```

I'm not sure why you are asking specifically for "distinct" records because with your example data you will get only 1 record, regardless if you add `DISTINCT` or leave it out.

If there would be more rows matching the given criteria, you have to exclude the `ID` column
(in case it is the Primary Key) to get distinct values for `Name`, `Fname`, `Mname` and `NID`. Then it would look like this:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        Name ,
        Fname ,
        Mname ,
        NID
FROM    tableName
WHERE   NID = 10
        AND Name <> 'a'
        AND FName <> 'y'
        AND Mname <> 'gg'
```

All other given answers seem to ignore your criteria specified in "Why exclude from the output list" so far.